# GdScript get node path on collision

Tags: game-engine, collision, game-physics, godot, gdscript

Say you have multiple areas, and when one overlaps, you want the script to get the node path of the overlapped node. In short, how do you get overlapped nodes’ node paths. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you handle a signal in the area (area_entered) and it will send the area object that you overlapped with. So you get that node directly, no need to get_node(nodepath).

[area2d](http://docs.godotengine.org/en/3.0/classes/class_area2d.html)

Answer (score 0):

When you connect the area_entered event from the Node Signals tab by the Inspector, the `_on_AreaNodeName_area_entered(area):` method will appear in your script. It will activate when something enters the CollisionShape that you have as a child, and the `(area)` part of that method represents whatever Object entered that space. Therefore, you can use the `get_path()` method to find that Object's path by doing `area.get_path()`.

To demonstrate, I made a 2D example with two Area2D nodes (AreaGreen and AreaRed) with basic sprites and collision shapes, and gave the one of them a label to display the path of any nodes that enter the area:

[Nodes used in Area Detection Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4NipF.png)

I gave the AreaGreen node simple horizontal movement, then connected the area_entered signal to the AreaRed node and wrote this script:

```
extends Area2D

func _on_AreaRed_area_entered(area):

    $Label.text = area.get_path()

    pass
```

To simply change the label text to the path of the intersecting node. Here are the results:

[Before the Areas collide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R0d8X.png)

[After the Areas collide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/q4xa3.png)

As you can see, the script successfully found the node path.